# g++ will not compile. fatal error: Files: No such file or directory windows

Tags: c++, windows

I am sure there is an answer out there for this but I cannot track it down.

code is simply

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::cout << "hello world";
  return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio runs the programs fine however when trying to compile from cmd

```
 Directory of C:\Users\ebump\OneDrive\Documents\test

05/20/2022  12:53 AM    <DIR>          .
05/20/2022  12:53 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/08/2021  06:42 PM             9,891 asuka.jpg
05/19/2022  08:18 PM        37,583,331 asuka2.jpg
05/20/2022  01:10 AM                82 steg.cpp
02/01/2021  05:32 PM        38,903,396 wet_circuits.wav
05/19/2022  08:15 PM        37,573,440 wet_circuits.zip
               5 File(s)    114,070,140 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  440,502,870,016 bytes free

C:\Users\ebump\OneDrive\Documents\test>g++ steg.cpp
steg.cpp:6:1: fatal error: Files: No such file or directory
```

what exactly is going on?

tried to update using Msys2

below is the output of g++ -v stegg.cpp

```
Reading specs from c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/specs
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program\ files\ (x86)/codeblocks/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.3/configure --prefix=/opt/windows_32 --with-sysroot=/opt/windows_32 --libdir=/opt/windows_32/lib --mandir=/opt/windows_32/man --infodir=/opt/windows_32/info --enable-shared --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --with-arch=pentium3 --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-checking=release --enable-libgomp --with-system-zlib --with-python-dir=/lib/python2.7/site-packages --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libssp --with-gnu-ld --verbose --enable-java-home --with-java-home=/opt/windows_32/lib/jvm/jre --with-jvm-root-dir=/opt/windows_32/lib/jvm --with-jvm-jar-dir=/opt/windows_32/lib/jvm/jvm-exports --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-antlr-jar='/home/adrien/projects/win-builds-1.5/slackware64-current/d/gcc/antlr-*.jar' --disable-java-awt --disable-gtktest --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentium3'
 c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/ -D_REENTRANT steg.cpp -quiet -dumpbase steg.cpp -mtune=generic -march=pentium3 -auxbase steg -version -IC:/Program Files (x86)/Codeblocks/include -o C:\Users\ebump\AppData\Local\Temp\ccUYYiRX.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.3 (i686-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.3, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 0.8.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/i686-w64-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/windows_32/opt/windows_32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/windows_32/mingw/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/Program"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/i686-w64-mingw32
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../include/c++/4.8.3/backward
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/include-fixed
 c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.3 (i686-w64-mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.3, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 0.8.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: c4fe4d0d4d1dfaca074c710f8d712c81
steg.cpp:6:1: fatal error: Files: No such file or directory
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Please [don't show images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions instead. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the way you installed or configured `g++`.  Please explain how you did that.

Comment: Honestly I cannot remember...

g++ --version shows 

g++ (GCC) 4.8.3

Comment: The quickest approach may just be to reinstall; you have a very old version anyway.  But if you really want to fix your current installation, then try compiling with `g++ -v steg.cpp` and post the output.

Comment: Is this your *actual* command and output? Did you redact it in any way?

Comment: Consider updating your compiler, GCC 4.8 is ancient. [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) provides an up-to-date version.

Comment: I tried to reinstall but I don't think I got rid of the old one correctly.

Comment: Updated the original post to include the g++ -v steg.cpp output

Comment: Use `@username` when replying in comments, otherwise we don't get notifications.

Comment: It's probably getting confused because of the spaces in the compiler path. But ultimately it doesn't matter, you need a new (up-to-date) compiler anyway, and MSYS2 installs to a path without spaces by default (unsure if its compiler would tolerate spaces or not). The output you're showing us is *not* from MSYS2, it's from your old compiler.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I figured it out, it was an incorrect path variable causing my issue, thank you so much for your support and suggestions through this

Answer (score 0):

Solved... issue was related to incorrect PATH variables

The problem was that C:\Program Files (x86)\Codeblocks\bin existed above C:\msys64\usr\bin in the system variables, so despite having updated g++ the system continued to look at the ancient version of g++ before the up to date version.

Comment: Can you explain more? If someone gets the same problem and finds this thread, it would be nice to have a proper answer waiting for them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If your program is working with Visual Studio IDE, you can compile it using VS Developer command prompt.

Please click the **Start Menu**, select **"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022"** it will open a terminal window, then navigate to the directory where your source code is located and run the following command

```
cl /EHsc test.cpp  # to compile the pogram
test.exe           # to run the program
```

[Visual Studio Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMcI4.png)

[Compile using cl compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcG78.png)